# Price break quantity for PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json, price

I have a array object like this

```
"PriceBreaks": [
  {
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Price": "$12.10",
    "Currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 5,
    "Price": "$11.76",
    "Currency": "USD"
  },
  {
   "Quantity": 10,
   "Price": "$11.42",
   "Currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 25,
    "Price": "$10.75",
    "Currency": "USD"
  }
],
```

I want to calculate the price based on quantity like json above.
My expected output like this

```
+ Quantity is 1 => price is $ 12.10
+ Quantity is 4 => price is 4 * $ 12.10
+ Quantity is 5 => price is 5 * $ 11.76
+ Quantity is 8 => price is 8 * $ 11.76
```

Any Help would be appreciated and thanks in Advance

Comment: It would be easier (and more likely) for someone to help you if you show us any attempt you've made to solve this problem so far (even if it's completely broken).

Comment: @Khoa Bui, did you make any progress on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another approach you may use for inspiration. See the comments for details.

```
<?php

// Raw JSON
$json = '[
  {
    "Quantity": 1,
    "Price": "$12.10",
    "Currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 5,
    "Price": "$11.76",
    "Currency": "USD"
  },
  {
   "Quantity": 10,
   "Price": "$11.42",
   "Currency": "USD"
  },
  {
    "Quantity": 25,
    "Price": "$10.75",
    "Currency": "USD"
  }
]';

// Convert JSON to array using the quantity as the index.
$offers = [];
// TRUE to convert to associative array.
foreach (json_decode($json, TRUE) as $offer)
{
    // Let's get a float for the calculations instead of the string.
    $offer['Price'] = +substr($offer['Price'], 1);
    // Store as quantity => offer.
    $offers[$offer['Quantity']] = $offer;
}

// The number of items to be purchased.
$customerQuantity = 10;

// max(1, ...) will ensure that the key will never go below 1.
// floor($customerQuantity / 5) * 5 to get to the nearest boundary. This assumes that quantities are always a multiple of 5!
echo $offers[max(1, floor($customerQuantity / 5) * 5)]['Price'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your calculation array where quantity and it's total price is stored.As you have stored the price with currency sign, before calculation you need to remove that character.

```
$json = '{
    "PriceBreaks": [{
        "Quantity": 1,
        "Price": "$12.10",
        "Currency": "USD"
    }, {
        "Quantity": 5,
        "Price": "$11.76",
        "Currency": "USD"
    }, {
        "Quantity": 10,
        "Price": "$11.42",
        "Currency": "USD"
    }, {
        "Quantity": 25,
        "Price": "$10.75",
        "Currency": "USD"
    }]
}';
  $data = json_decode( $json, true );
  $calculation = [];
  foreach ($data['PriceBreaks'] as $value) {
      $calculation [] = [
          'quantity' => $value['Quantity'],
          'total_price' => $value['Quantity'] * str_replace('$','', $value['Price'])
      ];
  }
  var_dump( $calculation );
```